# 2015 13" MacBook Pro Kernel Panics when waking from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, kernel-panic

For some reason when I wake my Mac from sleep the screen is black and none of the buttons work. Eventually, I get to the "your computer has restarted because of a problem" then I press any key to resume startup. Does anybody know why this might be happening?

I have a link to the log here.

https://pastebin.com/djJrSa0T

I am on Big Sur and reseting SMC and NVRAM didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSD driver is indicating a timeout after 100 seconds of attempting to transition from power-off to power-on states. There are a number of possible causes but one possibility is that your Mac, being the early 2015 MacBook Pro, has experienced significant wear on its SSD and some blocks are beginning to get worn, to the point of requiring grossly excessive time to read and write and tripping the 100 second time limit. However, my instinct is that a failure of this nature would produce a different cluster of behaviors.

We should, in every case of panic debugging, enable **kernel symbolication** so that your future panics contain a richer backtrace. To do this:

1. Run the following Terminal command: **`sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`**. Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a permission error, you will first need to **[disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection)**. You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)
2. Reboot your machine. The next time this panic occurs, your report will have a symbolicated backtrace. Please amend your question with a new link to it.

One thing that does stick out is that you've installed **Intel's Power Gadget**, which inserts a kernel extension into your system. Given that your panic occurs during the IOKit power state transition sequence, a reasonable experiment to try would be to run without this KEXT. The best way to do this is by **booting in Safe Mode** (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot) and trying to reproduce the failure.

**UPDATE:**

As the failure follows your SSD to another machine and also persists despite the removal of Intel Power Gadget, this gives a lot of support to the SSD being worn. I think you need to **migrate your data onto a new drive as soon as possible.**

Comment: This is a great answer, however, before doing anything at all, the OP should make sure he/she has a Backup!

Comment: @X_841 Well, yes, a backup is always a good idea. And if the SSD is worn, then the urgency of making a backup increases. However, if you are concerned that any of the steps I've given could directly cause damage, that is not the case; everything above is completely reversible and nondestructive.

Comment: @pion well I just did that and I have the logs here. Also worth noting that I took the SSD out of my MacBook Pro and put it into my MacBook Air and now it started crashing. Also there are 4 different log files in it. https://pastebin.com/aZKRm30u

Comment: @pion Here's another log with a different intro. https://pastebin.com/wWXAKV7N

Comment: @jimmysofat6864 Thanks for your excellent experimental data. Updated my answer.