# How to diagnose too many kernel panics on a 2017 21" Retina iMac running Monterey

Tags: mac, keyboard, display, kernel-panic

This on a 2017 Retina 21" iMac Running MacOS 12.4

The day before I installed 12.4 I had a kernel panic. The day after I installed it I had four kernel panics in rapid succession in the space of a half hour. Since then I have had more. Sometimes a day goes by without one, sometimes there are several in a day. I have read and, for the most part, followed this:

[If Your Mac Restarts and a Message Appears](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-mac-restarts-and-a-message-appears-mchlp2890/mac)

The Kernel-YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss.panic logs (/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/) offer no clues as to what software/hardware might be causing the panics

So far I have:

• Removed an external display and adapter
• Removed a USB hub
• Notremoved a non-Apple (Logitech) keyboard as the machine would be useless without it.
• Not removed an external drives as the machine would be useless to me without them

I started the machine in Recovery Mode and:

• Ran Disk First aid on the boot volume: No problems found
• Reinstalled MacOS

I started the machine in Diagnostics Mode and ran diagnostics: No problems found

The only extensions I have are those installed by:

• Graphic Converter
• Bartender
• Dropbox
• Google Drive
• Markup

The external drives that I have not removed have all been running fine on the machine for well over a year. I’ve had the keyboard for about 18 months.

I have attached the first few lines of the most recent panic report. This one happens to show that iStat menus was the panicked task, but I don’t think that means much. Every panic reports shows a different process as the panicked task.

Any ideas?

I have uploaded four .panic files. Complete links:

https://mgnewman.com/panic/Kernel-2022-05-27-160620.panic
https://mgnewman.com/panic/Kernel-2022-05-27-160805.panic
https://mgnewman.com/panic/Kernel-2022-05-27-163709.panic
https://mgnewman.com/panic/Kernel-2022-05-27-163923.panic

The should be downloadable with curl, or wget or even a web browser.

They should be symbolicated:

```
    <key>boot-args</key>
    <string>keepsyms=1</string>
```

Should be symbolicated, but, AFAIK, they are not. At least on this machine, changing that one NVRAM setting did not have the desired effect on the kernel panic files.

**MemTest86 Results**

```
MemTest86 V9.4 Free (Build: 1000) Result summary
PassMark Software
www.passmark.com
Test Start Time: 2022-06-02 00:00:27
Elapsed Time: 3:22:42
CPUs Active: 4
CPU Temperature Min/Max/Ave: 67C/81C/72C
RAM Temperature Min/Max/Ave: 100C/142C/125C
# Tests Passed: 48/48 (100%)
Lowest Error Address: N/A
Highest Error Address: N/A
Bits in Error Mask: 0000000000000000
Bits in Error: Total: 0 Min: 0 Max: 0 Avg: 0
Max Contiguous Errors: 0
```

**Safe Mode**

I booted into Safe Mode; something I'd never done before, so I didn't know what to expect. What I really didn't expect was what a slug the machine was in Safe Mode. It was barely useable. Instead of moving across the screen smoothly, the pointer moved in fits and starts. In text fields the insertion point simply disappeared now and then. I tried to use the machine that way, but was actually grateful when a kernel panic rebooted the machine in regular mode and the machine returned running as smoothly as normal. So weird. Is Safe Mode always like that?

Comment: Let’s start by following my instructions in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441239/macbook-pro-16-inch-2019-restarts-after-sleep-or-locking-the-screen/441383#441383 . Once you’ve done that and collected a few additional reports, please add (links to) all the new reports to your question. We should ideally look at several different symbolicated panics to see whether their signatures suggest a pattern.

Comment: The specific design intent behind SIP is to reduce the attack surface for **new** malicious code. As long as your currently installed set of third-party software is all from reputable vendors, then the only other potential vector is from a network (such as the internet). If you are interested in debugging your panics then you can disconnect from any public and private networks for the time being so that disabling SIP doesn't expose you to any elevated risk. You'll only have to stay off the net long enough to collect a few symbolicated panic reports.

Comment: If it's just the two, you can add them as code blocks directly in your question. For more than that, you can use something like www.PasteBin.com and add the links to your post. Make sure you've got the correct files: If the panics were symbolicated, you'll see human-readable function call stacks after the line ending in "Frame : Return Address"

Comment: You've correctly pointed out that symbolication appears to be missing for these reports. Just to be certain that the kernel picked up the boot arg before we look at next steps, can you tell me what `sysctl kern.bootargs` returns?

Comment: I already cleared the NVRAM since I'm certain that you can't get symbolized kernel panic reports by changing the boot-args. It may work for other reports, but not for the kernel. So, we're stuck with the reports that were generated. There have been many more.

Comment: That is incorrect. As an example, here are the panic reports in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430553/2015-13-macbook-pro-kernel-panics-when-waking-from-sleep/430555#430555 for before (https://pastebin.com/aZKRm30u) and after (https://pastebin.com/wWXAKV7N) symbolication was enabled.

Comment: Looks like your DRAM is fine. Great! Per my other notes: (#2) Have you had a chance to try running in Safe Mode yet? (#1) Can you tell me what interfaces/cables you're using to attach your external drives?

Comment: I added my observations about Safe Mode to the OP. At the moment I've booted without the two spinning (USB-A) drives. I'll leave it that way all weekend. All those two drives have are TM and CCC backups.

Comment: Re: Kernel panic in Safe Mode – does the panic report have the same signature? Re: Slowness in Safe Mode – Yes, that's typical. Among things that Safe Mode disables is the accelerated graphics drivers, so all rendering is done on-CPU which dramatically slows a low-end machine like a 21" iMac. Re: Drives – What I'd really want to try is living without the USB-C connection since that goes through the Thunderbolt controller which is one of the leading causes of MCE panics. Any chance that that drive has a USB-A port on it as well? Or even possibly leaving it detached for a little while?

Comment: I'm not smart enough to tell if it has the same signature. I don't know what to look for. - The USB-C drive is where most of my stuff is. And, I have a few shell scripts that write to it periodically. Without that drive the machine wouldn't be real useful. I will be away all weekend, so I will leave the machine as is (without the two spinning USB-A drives). No kernel panics since I removed them. If I get another panic I'll do what it takes to run without the USB-C drive.

Comment: I had a kernel panic with both spinning drives (USB-A) removed. I have now changed the SSD from a type C cable to a type A cable and reconnected both of the spinning drives.

Comment: Although it's probably too early to celebrate, I haven't had a kernel panic since I swapped cables on the SSD and connected it to a USB-A port on the iMac. It's been four days now.

Comment: Excellent! Let’s keep the experiment going.

Comment: OK. I'll leave everything as is.

Comment: The joy was premature. Another kernel panic this morning at 0521. pastebin.com/K16w6ME0 -- Same signature. And two more this afternoon. One at 1342 and the next at 1345. Both while I was watching TV and not using the iMac.

Comment: At this point there's little else left to try as an end-user other than running on a new install of macOS on a blank drive. If you can do that and still continue to get MCEs, then you're looking at either a macOS bug or a hardware issue, neither of which you can resolve without contacting Apple.

Comment: If I'm going to go through all that then it will be on a new machine. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've enabled kernel symbolication and we have found that it doesn't provided a human-readable backtrace. The possibilities for this are that (1) Apple has suddenly removed symbolication capability (unlikely), or (2) the addresses belong to a range that didn't map to a symbolicated region of the code. Neither of these would be expected behavior in this situation.

Furthermore, I'm not aware of any publicly available tools for decoding the `macOSProcessedStackshotData` field of the report, which might have turned up something actionable.

Nevertheless, we have some useful information even without symbols:

1. All four of your panic reports include the following **identical** signature:

   > ```
   > Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0a
   > family: 6 model: 158 stepping: 9 microcode: 240
   > signature: 0x906e9
   > Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz
   > 10 error-reporting banks
   > Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
   > IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb200000000030005
   > ```

   This signature means that your problem belongs to a class of panic called a **Machine Check Exception** (MCE), which is initiated in x86 silicon rather than by `xnu`. So, in all likelihood, the displayed backtrace would just show the MCE AST panic handler and indicate nothing about the origin of the MCE. This is strongly suggested by the fact that subtracting the KASLR slide from each of the frame return addresses yields an identical inner stack:

   > ```
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxx81c8d
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxxe1596
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxxd0963
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxx21a70
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxx8205d
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxx81816
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxx15163
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxxd19d7
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxx1c94c
   > 0xffffffxxxxxxxxxx : 0xffffffxxxxx222cf
   > ```

   That's the pattern in 3 of the 4 panics. The 4th one (`Kernel-2022-05-27-160805.panic`) appeared to have been in the middle of another operation when the AST occurred. It might have been marginally useful to know what it was doing but I'm guessing just `machine_idle()` or something like that.

   In other words: The backtraces aren't useful in this case.
2. Taking a look at [Intel's Software Developer's Manual, Vol. 4, Ch 15-16](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html), your report consistently shows that the first core-local MCA register (`MC0`) on your BSP (`Processor 0`) has an uncorrected internal parity error (`0xb...05`). What's more, the CPU wasn't able (or it didn't make sense) to identify an address that was associated with that error, so there is no `IA32_MC0_ADDR` register value to examine. The model-specific error code (`0x...3...`) is not decodable through public documentation so we don't know what it means for your specific CPU (*Core i5-7500*).
3. The fact that all four signatures are identical means that your issue is due to a specific, reproducible root cause.

And yet, despite these important clues, we simply don't have enough information or debugging tools available to get any more granular data on what the cause could be. MCE root causes span the entirety of hardware, firmware, and software – a bug in any of those can manifest as an MCE. Due to the low-level nature of MCEs and the fact that they halt CPU execution, the amount of useful diagnostic data that is able to be collected from a closed system at runtime from this generation Intel core is very limited (as compared to an "ordinary" kernel panic, when the CPU continues to fetch & execute instructions and `xnu` is often able to continue running to significant extent, allowing for interactive debugging).

What this means for you is that we're sort of stuck grasping at straws on our own. You indicate that you've done some hardware isolation experiments. There are only a couple of minor things I can think of there:

- What interface(s) **(cable(s))** are you using to connect your external drive(s) to your Mac?
- Can you try running in **Safe Mode** (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot) for a while and see if the panic goes away completely or still recurs?
- Can you try running an **[extended memory test](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)**? (Download the free version and `dd` the `memtest86-usb.img` image onto a flash drive, then boot from it.) Apple Diagnostics often misses errors that MemTest86 catches so run that and see if you get any errors (it'll take a while!).

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - If you got here by searching on "kernel panics" the short answer is that there are many things you can do to suss out the cause of kernel panics; none of which worked for me.

If you really want to go through all this, then read the excellent and informative comments by pion as well as the extensive suggestions in his answer to the question.

Comment: I'm not the best at interpreting kernel panics either, but it may be pure coincidence that you started getting kernel panics around the time of installing macOS 12.4? With my own kernel panic troubleshooting in the past, I'd reinstall macOS (maybe go back to the OS originally installed on your Mac) and see if a kernel panic gets triggered by that. If you don't get kernel panics from earlier macOS versions, then it suggests a software issue, but if you do get panics immediately after reinstalling macOS, it suggests that it is more than likely to be a hardware fault.

Comment: Note: Even if the Apple diagnostic test comes back fine, this doesn't exhaustively rule out hardware faults. Apple has their own in-house hardware test they plug into your computer, but even that can miss hardware faults. Example, Apple Genius found no hardware fault with my MacBook Pro with their in-house diagnostics tests, but after reinstalling macOS followed immediately by a kernel panic, the technicians ruled out software being the cause. It turned out that the logic board had failed, but they couldn't diagnose that without pulling apart my MacBook.

Comment: Assuming it is a hardware problem, what do I do next?

Comment: If it's a hardware fault, the only thing I'd recommend is get it in for service. Apple still manufactures parts for older models up to 7 years after your Mac model was first released. So you could go to Apple to get it replaced out of warranty. When I got my logic board replaced in my Macbook (5 years out of warranty), it cost $600-700 AUD for the board (that's the CPU, RAM, GPU all soldered on the one board), plus $100 AUD for Apple to service the new part. I had feared it was going to be exorbitantly high cost out of warranty, but it was actually quite reasonable.

Comment: Also, because of the logic board replacement, I've actually extended my Mac's life by another 3-5 years, which has saved me substantially from needing to buy a new Mac. This is a MacBook Pro from late 2013 (9 years ago) with 15" retina display, 2.6GHz Intel i7 Quad Core, 16GB RAM, 2GB of dedicated NVIDEA GPU, running macOS Big Sur. Surprisingly, it runs faster than my brother's 2020 Intel MacBook. So it is really up to you to consider weighing up the pros and cons of extending the life of your Mac vs buying an entirely new one.

Comment: I live in northeast Thailand. There are only two Apple stores in the country; both in Bangkok, about 250K from where I live. There is an authorized Apple repair shop near me, but I don't trust them very much. And, what would I tell them? This iMac might have a bad motherboard, but maybe not. Could I rely on them to do the proper diagnostics to determine if there really is a hardware fault? I don't think so.

Comment: In early December I took this iMac into the only shop in the city where I live that was willing to tackle repairing it. Six weeks later they called to say that they cannot repair it. They have no idea what's causing the kernel panics.