# Kernel Panics - Do these observations offer any clues?

Tags: imac, crash, kernel-panic

I realize that this is a huge longshot.

I have a 2017 21.5" Retina iMac currently running Ventura Public Beta 9. Beginning in May of this year I started getting regular Kernel Panics. I have done everything I can think of and (almost) everything suggested to diagnose the cause of these panics. I still have no idea. Read all about it here:

[How to diagnose too many kernel panics on a 2017 21" Retina iMac running Monterey](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441616/how-to-diagnose-too-many-kernel-panics-on-a-2017-21-retina-imac-running-montere)

And here:

[Is It Worth Repairing a 2017 iMac With Frequent, Irritating and Undiagnosable Kernel Panics?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/is-it-worth-repairing-a-2017-imac-with-frequent-irritating-and-undiagnosable-kernel-panics.2346159/)

Note that I'm not seeking further diagnostic help. I've already decided not to ask Apple to repair the machine. However, several months ago I started logging the panics to see if I could detect any pattern. Here's what I found:

• Many of the panics seem to come in clusters of two or more within a few minutes of each other:

```
Kernel-2022-09-25-081410.panic
Kernel-2022-09-25-081717.panic
Kernel-2022-09-25-082024.panic
```

• The machine never panics when I am away from home, even though the machine runs 24/7.

```
Kernel-2022-09-14-080601.panic
Kernel-2022-09-14-080930.panic

[Away from home 09/15-09/21]

Kernel-2022-09-22-084222.panic
Kernel-2022-09-22-195425.panic
```

• The machine rarely panics when I am using it. Most of the panics happen when I'm asleep or otherwise occupied. As a result, I have personally witnessed very few panics:

```
Kernel-2022-10-10-012503.panic
Kernel-2022-10-10-012817.panic
Kernel-2022-10-10-013241.panic
```

• The machine frequently has multiple panics after installing an OS update. These happen when the machine is booting after installation of the update:

```
[10/8 Installed Ventura Public Beta 8]

Kernel-2022-10-08-164919.panic
Kernel-2022-10-08-165238.panic
Kernel-2022-10-08-165805.panic
```

Is there anything to be learned from these observations?

An additional observation. After installing the release version of Ventura the panics dramatically increased in frequency. On 25 October there were 28. Previously it was rare for a panic to happen when I was using the machine. Now they happen often when I'm at the keyboard.

Since I'm now convinced that this is a hardware problem I decided to run memtest again; this time via the GUI remem. I first did ten loops which finished with no error. Yesterday morning I started a 100 loop run. It is now on loop 18. Still no errors.

**The observation:** Not one single panic while memtest is running. Why is that?

Comment: But you don't return the machine to a release OS because... reasons?

Comment: What difference would it make?

Comment: Release OSS are more stable. Where are you seeing the kernel .panic files stored?

Comment: The panics started last May when I was running release versions of Monterey. They continued unabated after I installed the release version of Ventura. The .panic files are stored here /library/logs/diagnosticreports and after a few hours are moved here /library/logs/diagnosticreports/retired. (I've added another observation to the original question.)

Comment: One other comment about Monterey and beta Ventura. With Monterey, when the machine booted after a panic there was no menu bar and the machine was unresponsive to keyboard input. I could fix that by logging in remotely and killing the WindowServer process. That would kick start the GUI and bring back the menu bar and make the keyboard work again. Installing the Ventura beta put an end to the WindowServer problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing to be learned from those observations.

As per you previous panic logs, we can say with a high degree of certainty that you have a hardware problem. Your alternatives are really to get the hardware fixed or live with the kernel panics.

I understand that you're not willing to test the machine with a non-beta operating system - that would of course be a reasonable thing to do before just accepting to live with kernel panics.

Comment: The machine started with the Kernel Panics long before I installed the Ventura Public Beta. I installed the Ventura Public Beta on September 11th. The panics began in May. I could go back, but why bother? If anyone can give me a good reason why going back would be advisable, I'd be happy to read them.

Comment: I didn't have that information at the time - so now you're saying that you already tried it on a non-beta OS - so you have already done it.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the panics are an indication of hardware errors. Not all panics are indications of hardware errors. These panics are indications of hardware errors. You need to fix the hardware.

Comment: What is it about the panic logs that indicate hardware error?

Comment: Most of those panics are machine-check exceptions. I.e. it's the CPU stopping all processing because it has detected a hardware error in the CPU, RAM or in the bus. This is almost always an indication of broken hardware - i.e. bad RAM, flawed CPU, etc. In the cases where it is not broken hardware, it is incorrect application of hardware - i.e. for example intentionally trying to overclock your CPU without supplying adequate cooling or failing to pair it with a power supply capable of supplying enough power.

Comment: Thanks for that. I still think it's interesting that the machine never panics when I'm away from home. I can't help but wonder if the panics are caused by one of the devices (Apple Watch, iPhone or iPad) that I always take with me.

Comment: I don't think having the machine repaired would be worth the money. The panics have turned out to be no big deal as they almost never happen when I'm using the machine. When they do, it's just another "time for coffee" notification.

Comment: Sure, if it's not worth it to you, then don't have the machine repaired. I'm just saying that in these cases, you can generally reinstall operating systems, device drivers, etc. all you want, but it won't solve the problem. I doubt that your problem is caused by an Apple Watch or iPad - that doesn't sound likely. However, it might be triggered by some external thing you do when you're home. This is not the same as saying that the external thing is the cause of the problem - the computer hardware being flawed is the cause - but it might be that this external thing triggers the problem.

Comment: In terms of what such an external thing could be - it might be something entirely unrelated. I.e. it could be that the panic happens when you use a near-by microwave, or when you turn on your dryer, or when you place that large power bank and charger right on top of your computer - or whatever it is you might do when you're at home.

Comment: Much of the time when it panics I'm doing nothing but lying in bed sound asleep. Nothing electrical gets turned on or off. Also, when I'm away from home there's always someone here who is likely to turn on the water pump, or microwave, or electric oven, or TV. I've been observing this for five months now and can find nothing that happens, either on the machine or in the house, that correlates with the panics. They seem to be entirely random except, of course, that they don't happen at all when I'm away; whether it's for one night (like this week) or ten.

Comment: @jksoegaard did the OP post the panic messages? How do you know it’s hardware? I’m asking because I’m seeing panics across three machines a lot more this year than ever in the past. I’d say it’s Monterey myself. Could be hardware. So how do you know it’s not related to moneterey?

Comment: @JamesRisner Yes, they were posted previously. You would need to look at the individual panic message to determine the cause. In general, panics can be caused by hardware as well as software - for example bugs in third party device drivers.

Comment: I created a bootable external drive with a pristine version of Monterey and with a single virgin user. No third party software. No third party kexts or device drivers. The machine still panicked when booted from that external drive. In fact, it panics in Safe Mode and in Recovery Mode.

Comment: @Buadhai Yes, you have a hardware issue. We have established that, so these panics are to be expected. But not all panics are like that, so James might see panics for a completely different reason.

Comment: I’d still like to know why it doesn’t panic when I’m away from home or when memtest is running. It’s a shame that Apple (or some third party) doesn’t supply better end-user tools to interpret panic reports and diagnose hardware failures.

Comment: Such a tool would be enormously complicated and probably would give wrong results in many cases. I think that’s the reason why such a tool is not supplied by Apple. Note that Microsoft does not provide such a tool for Windows either, and there’s also no such tool for Linux. Interpreting kernel panic reports is still a job for humans. HOWEVER that is not to say that Apple doesn’t provide a tool for finding the cause of the panic - they actually do! But it doesn’t work by interpreting the panic report - you need it running when the panic happens.

Comment: Where do I get the tool that finds the cause of the panic? BTW, the machine never panics when memtest is running. Four days now and not a single panic when memtest was running.

Comment: There is no such tool. Your problem is probably not memory-related then.

Comment: Well, at least now I know how to stop the machine from panicking. Continuously running memtest seems to work just fine.

Comment: In early December I took this iMac into the only shop in the city where I live that was willing to tackle repairing it. Six weeks later they called to say that they cannot repair it. They have no idea what's causing the kernel panics. They tried replacing the RAM, the SSD, and the power supply. They sent the logic board to a shop in Bangkok. Time to throw in the towel.